# Execute Randomforest model built using python in julia

Tags: python, julia, random-forest

Is it possible to use a randomforest model built in python to be exported and executed natively in julia? Will it give performance boost?

Comment: As it stands, this question doesn't have enough info to answer. How are you building the randomforest model?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [PyCall](https://github.com/JuliaPy/PyCall.jl) to call python code in Julia. Julia can't magically make Python code (or any other code) faster. You could call more basic components written in python and glue the desired end results together in Julia, which should theoretically be faster. For example, much of Scikit-learn uses Numpy, but you could call the Numpy library and construct the relevant code to create a random forest, which may be faster because Julia can compile the binding code. At this point it would make more sense to just use Julia entirely though, because most of Numpy's functionality is available Julia's LinearAlgebra package.

It's just a trade off how fast you want your code to be versus how much work you want to put into optimizing it.

Comment: What I meant is can a random forest model be saved to a file in python and used in Julia to predict for new values ?